# How can I create a dynamic object for multiple file types

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Is it possible to create a dynamic object based on an input file of multiple formats? (XML, Fixed Length, CSV)

I would think I should easily be able to handle the XML file, but I'm not sure if it's feasible to create a dynamic object off of a Flat File or CSV.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking here. Put it all in a string, that's a dynamic object that will hold any file right?

Comment: I'm not really getting a lot of details from business. Basically they want to input a XML/CSV/Flat file.  They want me to display all of the fields in the file and they will then select certain fields and create another output file based on the selected fields.

Comment: Then go request more information from the business!

Comment: I'm going to have to limit the scope down, say XML and possibly CSV, but what I'm looking for is a way to create a dynamic object based on CSV or Flat file.  I still need to look into FileHelpers, but I'm pretty sure I have to define the object a head of time.

Comment: Ha I better shot of getting hitting the lotto.

Comment: You don't really need a 'dynamic object'. From your comments, it seems all the data can be represented in table form (regardless of their input). So, write adapters from XML -> DataTable, CSV -> DataTable, etc. (You can use other 'forms' of data tables, such as collections of dictionaries, but this isn't too important). Once you've got it in the form of the table, you can allow them to select/remove columns, and then export the data table into various formats.

Comment: Standard business request "Can you make something that does everything we've thought of and everything we haven't. Thanks." :)

Comment: Maybe use DynamcObject - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Rob,  I like that approach.  I was too focused on creating an object than creating a table.